# Mixidity? Quantitative property of mixed subjects

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe the level(quantity) of a "mixture" or "mix".

For example A is more mixed than B. Hence A's "(the word I am looking for)" is bigger.

I thought of "mixability" but it is about the quality of being mixed. Then I thought something like "mixidity" but it doesn't exist in any dictionary.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The _concentration_ of B in A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to suggest the best word. But right word for mixability is miscibility.

Exploring the root of word emulsion might be helpful.

Also, in physical chemistry there is a possibility of finding the term you are looking for.

Comment: 'Mixability' isn't right?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth this is the first time I came across it. I was introduced to 'miscible'. Just now checked if "mixability" is a word, it is not found in Oxford Dictionary, but other sites list it.

Comment: **mixability** [noun]: 
Capacity for being mixed with something else. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mixability)] (Oxford's free online non-historical dictionary of English). And if it's in Lexico, it's almost certain to be in OED. 'Mixability' is an acceptable word. But neither it nor 'miscibility' mean 'the _degree_ of mixing'.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is the state of a **heterogenous mix**, or a mixture where two different samples may have elements in different proportion ([ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-heterogeneous-mixture-and-examples-605206)). If it were perfectly mixed, it would be **homogenous**.

So what you're investigating is the **heterogeneity** of a given mixture ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heterogeneity)):

> : the quality or state of consisting of dissimilar or diverse elements : the quality or state of being heterogeneous

This can be quantified, as Gy's sampling theory does ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_and_heterogeneous_mixtures)), in heterogeneity tests with various applications. Here's one in geology ([Geostats Pty Ltd](http://www.geostats.com.au/het_test.php)):

> The **heterogeneity test** uses the principles of Pierre M. Gy's Sampling Theory.

> The test work establishes appropriate sampling protocols for particular ores and allows for the design of sample flow sheets from the field through to sample preparation and assaying. Errors at each stage of sample size diminution can be calculated.

Comment: Hence, I could say "A's heterogeneity is bigger than B's". Right? And that would mean that A is more mixed (has more parts) than B.

Comment: Actually, in that example, A has greater homogeneity (is more homogeneous (or less heterogeneous) than B), and B has greater heterogeneity (is more heterogeneous (or less homogeneous) than A).

Comment: I am confused.. I thought heterogeneity means more of different things. A super homogeneous mix is all of the same thing hence less mixed. No?

Comment: Think of heterogeneity as the level of clumpiness in the mix, or to what degree the particles in a mixture are unequally distributed. More heterogeneity = more clumpiness. Larger cookie dough clumps in the ice cream. A super homogenous mix has been mixed so well that the particles are equally distributed.

Comment: Perfect!Thanks!

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin has provided exactly the right answer. If A is more mixed than B, A is more homogeneous than B. To your example, A's homogeneity is greater than B's.